# C3js graph loading issue

Tags: javascript, c3.js

When we open c3JS graphs in different tabs and navigate to and forth between the graphs. The graph is not getting populated. Instead if we refresh the page. the graph is getting loaded. Is the issue related to C3js library?

Answer (score 0):

Its not c3js issue. Redraw c3 chart when user click on tab menu. because chart DOM height and width will be zero when its hidden, After tab active you can redraw or use chart.resize() to redraw the chart.